# How to use openfiledialog to open any file as text in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, openfiledialog

I am writing a winforms program in C# that uses the openfiledialog. I would like it to be able to take the file that the user selected and open it as text, regardless of the file type.

I tried it like this:

```
if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    textBox1.Text = Process.Start("notepad.exe", openFileDialog1.ToString()).ToString();
}
```

However, that didn't work and I'm not sure if I"m even on the right track.

Comment: Huh? Are you looking for [System.IO.File.ReadAllText(pathAndFilename)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms143368.aspx)? -- btw. if it's not a text- or textlike-file (like an XML for example), "open it as text" will likely get you gibberish.

Comment: You expect Process.Start("notepad.exe" to return text?   You can only open it as text is it is a text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use this code:
First add this namespace :

```
    using System.IO;
```

Then add this codes to your function:

```
    OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
    openFileDialog.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
    if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog()== DialogResult.OK)
    {
            textBox1.Text = File.ReadAllText(openFileDialog.FileName);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

To open the file using notepad, you need to pass the file name as second parameter of `Start` method. For example:

```
using (var ofd = new OpenFileDialog())
{
    if(ofd.ShowDialog()== DialogResult.OK)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("notepad.exe", ofd.FileName);
    }
}
```

Also if for any reason while knowing that not all file contents are text, you are going to read the file content yourself:

```
using (var ofd = new OpenFileDialog())
{
    if(ofd.ShowDialog()== DialogResult.OK)
    {
        var txt = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(ofd.FileName);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing at the moment is starting a `Process` with the argument `openFileDialog1.ToString()`, calling `ToString()` on the process and setting this as text in the TextBox. If the path was valid, the result would probably be something like "System.Diagnostics.Process". But since you use `openFileDialog1.ToString()` as a path, your application probably crashes with a file not found error.

To get the selected file of an `OpenFileDialog`, use `openFileDialog1.FileName`. (See the docs [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog(v=vs.110).aspx))

What I think you actually want to do, is read from the file and write its contents as text to the TextBox. To do this, you need a [`StreamReader`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader(v=vs.110).aspx), like so:

```
if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    using(var reader = new StreamReader(openFileDialog1.FileName))
    {
        textBox1.Text = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

This way, you open the file with the StreamReader, read its contents and then assign them to the text box.

The `using` statement is there because a `StreamReader` needs to be disposed of after you're done with it so that the file is no longer in use and all resources are released. The using statement does this for you automatically.